# Highlight the text

Tags: jquery, html

How we highlight the whole div text element when click them. I use the following code

```
$("#ques22").css("background-color","#3BB9FF");
```

The ques22 is my div id. It also change the color of the image with in the div element.

Comment: Not a lot to go on here; have you written any code to handle the click event?

Comment: There also seems to be some confusion about what needs to be highlighted, so can you post an example snippet of HTML?

Comment: Do you want to select all text or highlight with a different background color ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a `p` tag an style that:

```
<div id="ques22">
   <p>text</p>
  <img src='src.jpg'/>
</div>

$('#ques22').click(function(){
    $(this).find('p').css("background-color","#3BB9FF");
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2eJeS/

Comment: You don't need the 'p' tag to style background color

Comment: @MikeRobinson of course, but he wants to style the texts not all the elements in the div. _"The ques22 is my div id. It also change the color of the image with in the div element."_

Comment: @undefined I think he wants to select all text when user clicks the element.

Comment: @undefined Sorry, my fault. There are some language barriers at work.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann yes, i thought a `p` tag can be a good option.

Comment: If you want to make this question truly html5 as it says it is, use the `mark` tag. :P

Comment: I want to ask a question if i click ask question it says..Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. what can i do if i ask a questions..

Comment: @Dinesh maybe because you have been downvoted more than 10 times, i will uvpvote your question, hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than .css() , try addClass() like this, you'll get more control via css this way

http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/MPaDc/

Comment: if i have a div like this <div id="ques22" class="ques">. Does  addclass() function affects the class "ques"?

Comment: no, it wouldnt.
well if you are using class, ques, just change the # into . (dot)

Comment: Tip: Notice the css, cursor-hand? if you ever wanted to make it as pointer, without using <a tags

Comment: Sorry, thats a bit confusing... can you edit your last comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following if you want to style your text:

**JS**

```
$('div.yourClass').toggle(function() {
    $(this).html(function(i, text) {
        return $('<span>', {'class': 'highlighter', 'text': text});
    });
},
function() {
    $(this).html($('span', this).html());
});
```

**CSS**

```
.highlighter {
    color: red;
}
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/bs7p4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use this give a shadow effect and highlight them

`#ques22 {
            -webkit-transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
            -moz-transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
            -ms-transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
            -o-transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
            transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
         }`

the id of the ques22 must have a shadow effect then only this code will work

`$("#ques22").css({'text-shadow': '0 0 20px red'});`